# How change state of widget using GetX Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I would like this widget (TabButton) change its state and run isSelected func ever currentPageIndex value changes in controller.

My widgets:

```
Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Obx(
            () => TabButton(
              title: 'AGORA',
              onPress: () => widget.pageController.jumpToPage(0),
              isSelected: _controller.isSelected(0),
            ),
          ),
          Obx(
            () => TabButton(
              title: 'AGENDA',
              onPress: () => widget.pageController.jumpToPage(1),
              isSelected: _controller.isSelected(1),
            ),
          ),
          Obx(
            () => TabButton(
              title: 'FAVORITOS',
              onPress: () => widget.pageController.jumpToPage(2),
              isSelected: _controller.isSelected(2),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

My controller:

```
class RootScreenController extends GetxController {
  Rx<int> currentPageIndex = 1.obs;

  // It's called in PageView
  void pageChangged(int index) {
    currentPageIndex.value = index;
  }

  bool isSelected(int buttonIndex){
    return currentPageIndex.value == buttonIndex;
  }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but state of buttons doesn't change.

Comment: Where is your widget.pageController coming from? What is the ```jumpToPage()``` function like? Your code should work assuming you are getting the correct controller and the function is working as intended

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure the Obx widget is properly listening to changes in the Rx currentPageIndex.

```
Row(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Obx(
        () => TabButton(
          title: 'AGORA',
          onPress: () => widget.pageController.jumpToPage(0),
          isSelected: _controller.currentPageIndex.value == 0,
        ),
      ),
      Obx(
        () => TabButton(
          title: 'AGENDA',
          onPress: () => widget.pageController.jumpToPage(1),
          isSelected: _controller.currentPageIndex.value == 1,
        ),
      ),
      Obx(
        () => TabButton(
          title: 'FAVORITOS',
          onPress: () => widget.pageController.jumpToPage(2),
          isSelected: _controller.currentPageIndex.value == 2,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

This modification will ensure that the Obx widget directly observes the currentPageIndex.value, which should result in the correct behavior when the currentPageIndex value changes.